# UI web view attached to email

Tags: ios5, uiwebview, xcode4.2, html-email

Im trying attach a UI webview to the email body in my project.  I have a combination of text fields and ui webview. When I try to attach the UI WebView the text boxes ok appear but the the uiwebview contents do not.

```
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textfieled.text,webview.tag];

[mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

I realise the .tag might be incorrect on the webview, could someone tell me what i should be putting there (or doing wrong)as I have tried all combinations available?

Comment: What is your code to show the UI Webview at the moment?

Comment: `UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
    
 if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
 }
    
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    
    
}
    
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        
 
 
 }`